# is it possible to use a subfolder for hydrogen / oxygen deployments with shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-hydrogen

I want to have my repo setup to have two folders;

CMS
Storefront

I then want to tell hydrogen to use the shopfront folder for deployments.

Is that possible?